# Dimension of connected components of $O(n)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, orthogonal-matrices

The special orthogonal group $SO(n)=O_+(n)$ is the subgroup of the orthogonal group $O(n)$ containing matrices with determinant $+1.$ The other connected component of $O(n)$, call it $O_-(n)$, has matrices with determinant -1.

I always thought $O_+(n)$ and $O_-(n)$ had the same dimension and were in fact isomorphic. However the following consideration shaked this belief when $n$ is even.

The eigenvalues of $g\in O(2m)$ are either real or come in complex conjugate pairs. If all eigenvalues are complex, then the determinant is positive and $g\in O_+(2m)$. The only chance for $g$ to belong to $O_-(2m)$ is if some eigenvalues are real and an odd number of them are $-1$. This stringent condition seems to imply that $O_-(2m)$ has lower dimension than $O_+(2m)$.

Is that true? In even dimension almost all orthogonal matrices are in fact special?

Comment: $O(n)$ is disconnected with two homeomorphic components/cosets:  $SO(n)$ and its complement.

Comment: If your argument about eigenvalues is right, why would that mean that $O_{-}(2m)$ has lower dimension than $O_+(2m)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might help you to understand the connection between degrees of freedom and eigenvalues when thinking more geometrically.

Take $n = 2$. Here every elements of $O_+$ is a rotation around the origin and every element of $O_-$ is a relection in a plane through the origin. Suppose you would actually use this as the definition of $O_+$ and $O_-$ and try to compute how big the sets of rotations and reflections are using your eigenvalue/eigenvector idea...

Reflections are the easy ones. Just by thinking about what it means to be a reflection we see that it has eigenvalue 1 with eigenvectors all lying on the 'mirror' and and eigenvalue -1 lying on the line perpendicular to the mirror. So we have zero degrees of freedom in choosing the eigenvalues but that doesn't mean the set of reflections in mirrors passing through the origin is zero-dimensional because we can still choose the location of the 1-eigenvector. The location of the $(-1)$-eigenvector is then fixed.

In other words we see from a purely geometric perspective that the space $O_-(2)$ itself has the topology of a the projective line (the set of all lines through the origin in the plane) which is 1-dimensional, homeomorphic to a circle. (Perhaps it is more correct to say that it is a circle with its antipodal points identified, which by some quirk of nature is itself homeomorphic to a circle.)

By contrast in the set of rotations the situation concering eigenvalues and eigenvectors is more or less 'reversed'. Rotations seemingly have *no* eigenvectors which naively could be seen as a reason to believe that $O_+(2)$ is zero-dimensional. But as you noted in this case we have something we did not have in the reflection case: the freedom to choose an eigenvalue. So there still is a degree of freedom.

Now from a geometric perspective it is hard to understand what an eigenvalue 'is' when there are no eigenvectors, but in the geometric picture there is a different and much easier way to describe the degree of freedom: it is just the angle over which you rotate. It is clear that the set of angles together has the topology of a circle. So both $O_+(2)$ and $O_-(2)$ are circles and hence diffeomorphic.

One way to talk this back to eigenvalues, though, is to view the entire plane as a one-dimensional complex eigenspace. The rotation is then just the multiplication with the single eigenvalue associated to that space (the second eigenvalue acting on a different, 'invisible' plane we can safely ignore as our interest is in degrees of freedom and we already knew that the second eigenvalue is completely determined by the first eigenvalue that we 'do' see)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if $M\in O_-(n)$, then$$\begin{array}{ccc}O_+(n)&\longrightarrow&O_-(n)\\N&\mapsto&MN\end{array}$$is a diffeomorphism. So, yes $\dim O_+(n)=\dim O_-(n)$.

Comment: This makes sense, but what is wrong with my argument involving eigenvalues?

Comment: If $M\in O(2m)$, in order to have $M\in O_+(2m)$, $M$ has to have an even number of real eigenvalues equal to $-1$, and in order to have $N\in O_-(2m)$, $M$ has to have an odd number of real eigenvalues equal to $-1$. I don't see why the second condition is more stringent than the first one.

Comment: No, $M$ can belong to $O_+(2m)$ by having all eigenvalues complex. Since they come in complex conjugate pairs, the product is always positive

Comment: In that case, $M$ has $0$ real eigenvalues equal to $-1$. Last time I checked, $0$ is an even number.

Comment: Ok, but I am trying to count degrees of freedom. If you don't need to impose that any eigenvalues are real, you have more freedom, higher dimension, than in the case when some eigenvalues are fixed. No?

Comment: Imposing that not any are real is imposing that all are complex, so is that really more "freedom"?

Comment: In the first case you have $n$ arbitrary phases. In the other case you have only $n-1$ arbitrary phases. So the first seems to be a larger space.

Comment: That only shows that counting the number of possible eigenvalues doesn't give the dimension. Just take $O(2)$. Both $O_+(2)$ and $O_-(2)$ are $1$-dimensional, but, yes, there are more possibilities (as far as types of eigenvalues are concerned) and the case of $O_+(2)$ than in the case of $O_-(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g=\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1,1\ldots,1)\in O_-(n)$.  The map $h\mapsto gh$ induces a bijection between $O_+$ and $O_-$.

Comment: This makes sense, but what is wrong with my argument involving eigenvalues?

Comment: Your argument with eigenvalues doesn't actually do anything to specify dimension.  It implies that it does, but it never makes the leap beyond gentle winking.  The structure of the eigenvalues will impact the dimension of the conjugacy class of your matrix (e.g., if they are all 1, then you have to be the identity matrix), but the interplay between dimension of conjugacy classes and dimension of the whole space is subtle.

Comment: Correct.  It is not clear why the eigenvalue argument should relate to the dimension at all.

Comment: In the first case you have $n$ arbitrary phases. In the other case you have only $n−1$ arbitrary phases. So the first *seems* to be a larger space. Maybe this is actually wrong, but to me it seems intuitive.